# POST req body return empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i have a problem when POST some data in POSTMAN my problem is during "post" method /auth/login req.body return empty array.
Postman return empty object only if i use POST method with use form-data, if i change to xxx-www-form-urlencoded whatever works fine. I wanna know why it works so

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;



app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/assets"))


app.post('/auth/login', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json(req.body)
})



mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log('port' + port)
        })
    })
```

Comment: postman return empty object only if i use POST method with use form-data, if i change to xxx-www-form-urlencoded whatever works fine. I wanna know why it works so

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `xxx-www-form-urlencoded` and you mean `multipart/form-data` instead of `form-data`.

These 2 content-types are completely different encodings. When you called:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

You added a middleware that can parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but that does not mean it automatically parses other formats too. It's only for that format, just like `express.json()` is only for the `application/json` format.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this, i just created multer in my controller and it work how i wanted

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { getUsers, createNewUser } = require('../controllers/newUser')
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');


const upload = multer();


router.get('/', getUsers)

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => res.send('get single user'))
router.post('/', upload.none(), createNewUser)



module.exports = router;
```